# Border on subset of pages

Tags: color, edge

I want a gray border on the outside edges of pages of specific chapters in a textbook to obtain the visual effect that looking at the closed text pages you can spot the relevant special chapters.  Best approximation has been:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,letterpaper]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Math book you paid too much for}
\author{Your professor}

\chapter{History lesson}
\lipsum

\pagecolor{gray!20}
\chapter{The Fundamental Theorem}
\lipsum

\pagecolor{white}
\chapter{Stuff you will forget}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

But this changes the entire background color instead of a stripe on the edge.  Saw and fiddled with `\AddToHook` cannot seem to switch between edged and unedge pages with that one.  Is there another package or approach for this sort of goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add content to the `B`ack`G`round using [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) and condition on whether the page number is odd/even. The code below add little "thumbs" to the edge of the paper. You can adjust the placement and size.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum,eso-pic}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum

\cleardoublepage
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \raisebox{.75\paperheight}{%
      \ifodd\value{page}
        \hspace*{\dimexpr\paperwidth-3em}%
      \fi
      \textcolor{black!15}{\rule{3em}{2em}}%
    }%
  }%
}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\lipsum

\cleardoublepage
\ClearShipoutPictureBG
\chapter{Final chapter}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

`\ClearShipoutPictureBG` removes any insertion placed by `\AddToShipoutPictureBG`.